# Selecting last event given certain conditions

Tags: mysql

In [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87383/5) you may find the query I'm working on actually. I have a database table which holds events from users which are logging in and out in their telephones.

I have a query which, basically, select an agent only if it's virtually "logged" but within the logging event, you may have other status such as being talking or being in administrative time.

What I want to achieve is to get the LAST status for those agents who are logged.

Please, note that it's not possible to be unlogged and then have another status related to logged status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM eventos_centralita a
LEFT JOIN eventos_centralita b 
  ON b.codAgente = a.codAgente 
  AND b.evento = 'Deslogado'
  AND b.fechaHora > a.fechaHora
LEFT JOIN eventos_centralita c
  ON c.codAgente = a.codAgente 
  AND c.fechaHora > a.fechaHora
WHERE b.idEvent IS NULL AND c.idEvent IS NULL AND a.evento <> 'Deslogado' GROUP BY a.codAgente;
```

Comment: Thanks Charles but it doesn't, it gives me back rows 6 and 3 and should be 6 and 7 because the last status is 'Administrativo' instead of 'Logado'

Comment: Edited the query to only return the latest events. I have the feeling I'm being wasteful somewhere but I'm not awake enough to figure out where.

Comment: Also not sure how many rows you have in the DB but try altering the schema by adding: KEY `joinAgent` (`codAgente`, `evento`, `fechaHora`)